# Работа через DataAdapter с большими данными

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Существует ли в природе, какой-нибудь ленивый `DataAdapter`, который вытягивает в `DataSet` записи по мере их необходимости или по N записей за раз?

Иногда не рационально грузить в память все данные в виду их большого объема и хочешь выполнять обновления по немногу, возвращать данные назад на сервер и брать следуюущую порцию.

Есть что-нибудь готовое?

Конечно, можно ручками реализовать, но быть может уже что-то придумано до меня и не нужно делать велосипед?

Comment: Возможно это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937548/filling-dataset-with-dataadapter-with-row-limit

строка da.Fill(ds, 1, maxRowCount, ds.Tables[0].TableName);

Comment: @NMD похоже на то, что нужно. Получается все равно придётся какую то логику закладывать, что бы тянуть каждый раз новые записи. А можно автоматом и все зависимые записи других таблиц подтянуть в виде отдельных таблиц в Дамаскин?

Answer (score 1):

Используй `Hibernate` для таких целей. Мануалов много, но идея в том, что ты указываешь `setFirstResult` и  `setMaxResults`, где указываешь промежутки.

```
public List<Cat> findCats(String name, int offset, int limit) {

    Query q = session.createQuery("from Cat where name=:name");

    q.setString("name", name);

    if (offset > 0) {
        q.setFirstResult(offset);
    }
    if (limit > 0) {
        q.setMaxResults(limit);
    }

    return q.list();

}
```

Есть готовое решение уже в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168084/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-of-making-pagination-in-hibernate-than-executing-s)

Comment: Hibernate, на сколько я знаю- это ORM? А заталкивать данные назад я смогу без проблем? С СУБД Access он дружит?

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, это ORM.  
Hibernate позволяет толкать данные куда хотите, можете даже сначала набрать данные в кэше, а потом записать  в базу. 
вот пример на ms Access   http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550948/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-dataadapter-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8/553429?noredirect=1#comment712998_553429

Comment: Ссылка что-то не работает.

Comment: @iluxa1810 извиняюсь. вот 
http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2011/06/how-to-use-ms-access-with-hibernate.html